# regex to remove dash between alphanumeric

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex to remove dash between alphanumeric. Any leading or tailing dash should not be removed.

For example, `abc-edd` would result in `abcedd`.

I tried

```
Regex.Replace(json, @"^\w-^\w", "");
```

However it is not doing anything.

Comment: Why not `return yourInputString.Replace("-", "");` instead of a regex?

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik Because that would remove leading and trailing hyphens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
@"(?<=\w)-(?=\w)"
```